# Converting Jenkins from http to https with an ssl certificate from Let's Encrypt running on Nginx

Tags: nginx, jenkins, keystore

I have the following prerequisites:

- Jenkins running on port 8080
- Nginx installed and configured so that it pulls the certificates installed from Let's encrypt
- keystore also is installed and the path to the .jks is described in /etc/default/jenkins

The outcome that I want to achieve is:

Assigning my Jenkins a specific domain name which is bound to an IP address, for which the certificates are correctly set to their path in the nginx conf. file. I need to access my Jenkins through my domain name and https connection without specifying a port.

( I am a Dev/Ops intern, so excuse me for not being very descriptive )

Comment: You could start by trying to specify proxy_pass with the URL for the Jenkins server ([reverse proxy](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/))